# Finding raster calculator input in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I am using the raster calculator in QGIS 2.18.11, and I want to find the equation/input that went in the "raster calculator expression" box for rasters that have already been created with the raster calculator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately QGIS 2.18 Raster calculator does not keep history of expressions or input parameters.

However, if we run Raster calculator in QGIS 3.0 from `Processing Toolbox | QGIS Raster analysis`, there is a `Log` window (available until we close the session).

We can also *Save* our own expressions for future use.